# If $div$ $f$ not change sign in a cell closed and two-dimensional in $\Omega$, then $\Omega$ It does not contain periodic orbits $x' = f(x)$

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having problem in this exercise, I'm trying to Green's theorem and demonstrate by contradiction, thanks for the help.

Show that if $div$ $f$ = $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial f_1}$ $+ ... +$ $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial f_n}$ not change sign in a cell closed and two-dimensional in $\Omega$, then $\Omega$ does not contain periodic orbits of $x' = f(x)$

Sorry for the mistakes in the translation. I am Brazilian.

$\textbf{Remark}:$ $f=(f_1,...,f_n)$ and $\Omega$ is the domain the $f$ where it is continues.

Comment: I don't want to mess up your question if the meaning was supposed to be different, but I think you mean sign instead of signal.

Comment: I think so, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove this using the Divegence Theorem.  If your orbit bounds a region $D \subset \Omega$ then
$$ \int_D (\nabla \cdot F) dA = \int_{\partial D} F \cdot \hat{n} ds$$
where $F$ is a vector field and $\hat{n}$ is the normal vector at each point on the boundary (the orbit).

Take the vector field $F$ to be $f$ and without loss of generality assuming it is always positive in $\Omega$.  Then:
$$ \int_D (\nabla \cdot f) dA > 0$$

On the other hand $x(t)$ parametrizes the boundary $\partial D$ so:
$$\int_{\partial D} F \cdot \hat{n} ds = \int_{\partial D} f \cdot \hat{n} ds = \int_{\partial D} \dot{x} \cdot \hat{n} ds$$
But by definition of the normal vector (being perpendicular to the boundary, i.e. $x(t)$) this integrand is always $0$ so the entire integral is zero.  So we arrive at a contradiction.

$$ \int_D (\nabla \cdot F) dA > \int_{\partial D} F \cdot \hat{n} ds$$